# Yii render Javascript file on view

Tags: php, javascript, yii, include

I want to include JavaScript file in my view.

And I want to render it together and not as script file (registerScriptFile).

How can I do that?

Comment: use [`registerScript()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScript-detail)

Comment: By using registerScript I can't load it from file.

Comment: just read the file using `file_get_contents()` and use its output in `registerScript()`

Comment: Simply add a `<script src="..."></script>` tag to the view?

Comment: I'm wondering - why do you want to do this in the first place? I don't understand what's the reason of not willing to include JS file as it's done normally. Why do you need to include content of JS file like that?

Comment: I want to render JS file that I already have in my system.
I don't want to maintenance php file with js code because IDE cannot highlight color and debug JS inside php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `renderFile()` it would render any file, remember to wrap it with `<script>` tag.

Comment: So you should use `renderFile`, and add extension. Should work fine, ie: `$this->renderFile('some/file.js')`. I also edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, This is the final results.

public function actionRenderJS() {

         header("Content-type: text/javascript");
         $js_file = 'scripts/widget.js';

                 $this->renderFile($js_file);

         Yii::app()->end();
     }